USB-C display is detected but only shows black screen (AMD Ryzen 7 2700U, Linux Mint)
I just got myself a Samsung S27A600UUU. I was hoping to attach it via USB-C to my Lenovo E585 and use it as both the laptops power cable and the display cable.
The power part works as expected, but the display part does not. When I attach the monitor to the laptop, the OS correctly recognizes the attached display, including correct resolution and refresh rate. However, while I can configure it in the Display app all I want, no image is actually shown. The display claims that the laptop does not send any signal and correspondingly only shows black.
Attaching the laptop via HDMI works fine, but I was hoping to cut down on that cable. Anybody got a clue as to what might be the cause here?
Output of xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.98 +  47.98  
   1680x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.98  
   1440x900      59.98  
   1280x800      59.98  
   1280x720      59.98  
   1024x768      59.98  
   800x600       59.98  
   640x480       59.98  
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 337mm
   2560x1440     59.95* 
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     75.00 +  59.95  
   1920x1200     75.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     75.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Output of lspci -vv that relates to graphics devices:
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c3) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 44
    IOMMU group: 13
    Region 0: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 2: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Region 5: Memory at c0800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

I also saw this question on askubuntu, but that seems to relate to an nvidia graphics card. I did try adding amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, but that did not change anything.
